# Visual studio 2010 addin "Edit.Copy" Command

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, ide, add-in

I created some Addin for VS2010 Which present some toolwindow with some WPF application.
I have some command in my WPF app for example Copy, Paste and etc, which I want to bind to the VS command. 
So far I succeeded to "listen" to the Copy command of VS but my problem is when My ToolWindow is Displayed, The Copy command of VS is disabled. 
How can I enabled the Copy command? Is it has something with the fact that i'm using NoToolWindow configuration?

Should I try to hook the keyboard event?

Anyone??

Thank you, Leon